# What is the probability that Silver coin is drawn again?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Two boxes contain coins. One box has $1$ silver and $3$ gold coins, the other box has $2$ silver coins and $1$ gold. A box is randomly chosen, and a coin is randomly selected. The coin is found to be silver. If a second coin is selected from the same box what is the probability that it will be silver also?

My try:
I have found the following probabilities:
let $A$ is an event that Box $1$ is chosen,$S$ be an event the coin is silver.
Also $A^c$ is the event of choosing Box $2$.

By Bayes Theorem we have:
$$P(A/B)=\frac{P(B/A)P(A)}{P(B/A)P(A)+P(B/A^c)P(A^c)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\times 0.5}{\frac{1}{4}\times 0.5+\frac{2}{3}\times 0.5}=\frac{3}{11}$$
Like-wise
$$P(A^c/B)=\frac{P(B/A^c)P(A^c)}{P(B/A)P(A)+P(B/A^c)P(A^c)}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}\times 0.5}{\frac{1}{4}\times 0.5+\frac{2}{3}\times 0.5}=\frac{4}{11}$$

Any help here?

Comment: Your arithmetic is off.  These probabilities must sum to $1$, and it is obvious that your fractions (pre-arithmetic) sum to $1$. (Note:  I guess that $B=S$?  Anyway, you should clarify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a calculation error.  We must have $$\Pr[A \mid B] + \Pr[A^c \mid B] = 1.$$  The second probability should be $\Pr[A^c \mid B] = 8/11$.

The rest of the question is straightforward:  the probability that the second coin drawn from the same box is also silver is equal to $$0 \Pr[A \mid B] + (1/2) \Pr[A^c \mid B] = 4/11.$$  This is because if the box that was chosen was the first one, there are no more silver coins to be drawn.  If the box was the second one, then of the remaining two coins in the box, one is silver and will be drawn with probability $1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Everything looks good except the final value due to an arithmetic error. I get $P(A^C | B) = \frac{8}{11}$. You can tell something is wrong since you must have $P(A|B) + P(A^C|B) = 1$.

The last step is to calculate the probability of choosing another silver coin, given that a silver coin was chosen. Let $C$ be the probability that the second coin is silver. Then:
$$P(C) = P(C|\text{box 1})P(\text{box 1})+P(C|\text{box 2})P(\text{box 2}).$$
Conditioning on the fact that we already saw a silver coin (even $B$):
$$P(C) = P(C|A,B)P(A|B) + P(C|A^C,B)P(A^C|B).$$
So you just need to find $P(C|A,B)$ and $P(C|A^C,B)$. The problem did not explicitly state that the silver coin is replaced before the second draw, so keep that in mind when finding these probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation for $P(A^c|S)$ has a mistake. What you have written evaluates to  $8/11$ or simply note that $P(A^c|S) = 1 - P(A|S) = 8/11$.

Now the only way you can get a second silver coin is by choosing box $2$ and after the first coin is drawn from box $2$, it will have two coins left and one of them is a silver coin.

So the desired probability is,

$ \displaystyle \frac{8}{11} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{4}{11}$